# ASP.NET MVC + sending encoded string using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

On my website, I'm using jquery ajax to send data to a controller. How can I encode data using jquery/javascript, so I can send strings like javascript code, etc ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm interested in reading about a scenario in which it makes sense to pass JavaScript code as a variable via AJAX.

Comment: Would you like to send Javascript code from the client **to the server** or from the server **back to the client**?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somecontroller/someaction',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { value: 'some string' },
    success: function(result) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

and the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string value)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I know how to use jquery ajax, my question is about encoding. Thanks

Comment: @macpak, what exactly do you want to encode and what problems did you encounter?